# Eclipse Mars: Import from svn is not found

Tags: eclipse

I want to download/import a project from svn. But that option is not there in my workspace. I think i need to add some plugin. Anyone please help me to do this.
Attached the screenshot

[image]

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: you have to install Subclipse plugin

Comment: thank you! i installed the plugin from eclipse market place. now i am able to checkout project from svn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download or install Subclipse plugin from eclipse market place. After that make a checkout of project, only then you can link or keep in sync your workplace with svn through Subclipse plugin.[tutorial to install Subclipse in eclipse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S0tGGB_tvc)

Comment: thank you! i installed the plugin from eclipse market place. now i can checkout from svn